# Getting values from Posts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I loop through, and get these values from the Posts node? I'm still new to Firebase... Also using Java.

I'm targeting the specific user key, by:

```
mPostsRef.child(userKey)
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the body and title, try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(userKey);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String body=datas.child("body").getValue().toString();
      String title=datas.child("title").getValue().toString();
    }


}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

The snapshot will be at direct key under the node `Posts` then you can loop inside the random keys and get the values of body and title.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question. What if I edit the data? addChildEventListener has a method onChildChanged, but I just can't seem to get it working right. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep the location as it is, dont use the for loop and retrieve inside onChildAdded

Comment: Yeah I did that. I've added a Toast for onChildAdded for testing purposes. But, when I restart the app, the toast shows a few times instead of one. Also, when I add another node, the toast repeats a few times too. Not sure why...

Comment: you need to use AddSingleValueEvent instead of childeventlistener so it does not repeat

Comment: Ohh alright. Sorry for the confusion, but if I do that, how would I be able to access the other methods such as onChildChanged? Again, I apologise

Comment: You can't access it if you do that. But I meant addsinglevalueventlistener is used to only read once thus preventing more than one toast